# Add http:// to the beginning of submitted url

Tags: php

I am looking the best way to add http:// to a submitted url. I have a site that allows users to submit their website url when signing up, the problem is some user type "example.com" some users type "www.example.com" and some type "http(s)://example.com"

What I would like to accomplish is to make sure the end result is "http(s)://example.com" regardless of what they submit.

Is there any way to do this and still account for other things like co.uk or https?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that, I am looking for something that works with php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need of REGEX. REGEX are often a lot expensive. Here's a home made function that achieve your goal:

```
function fix_url($url) {
    return (substr($url, 0, 7) == 'http://' || substr($url, 0, 8) == 'https://')
        ? $url 
        : 'http://'.$url;
}
```

Samples:

```
$url = 'example.com';
$url1 = 'httpexample.com';
$url2 = 'http://example.com';
$url3 = 'https://example.com';

echo fix_url($url);
echo '<br>';
echo fix_url($url1);
echo '<br>';
echo fix_url($url2);
echo '<br>';
echo fix_url($url3);
echo '<br>';
```

Output:

```
http://example.com
http://httpexample.com
http://example.com
https://example.com
```

If you have any doubt, please consider adding a comment below.

References:

- [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: what if the URL provided uses a protocol other than http?

Comment: @Ryan, the OP didn't mention it.

Comment: That should work just fine for what I need, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To account for http(s)://, this is very straight forward since there are two options only to check. i.e. check that the link starts with "http://" or "https://", if not then add "http://".

The other part of your question which is to account for ".co.uk", you can either gather all available suffixes in a dictionary which is a very bad idea or you can simply check for the presence of a "." leaving what comes after the "." to the user's responsibility.

I hope I answered your question :)

Comment: Yes, I would definitely rather leave anything after "." up to the user, I figure, if they want people to find their site they should make sure its correct.

as for looking for http(s), should I do this with regex? I have seen a lot of regex and Im not skilled enough yet to know which one will work, seems as though there are thousands of regex out there, all different.

That part is important, because it dictates how I link to their site, when someone enter example.com, it just creates a link like http://www.MySite.com/example.com which of course is no good.

Comment: No need for Regex, it is costly and your case here is a very simple string matching. Regarding "MySite.com/example.com", you have now way to validate if the site is wrong or not, but simple checks like checking for multiple dots, semicolon...etc. can help you find mistyped sites and notify the user. Other than that I don't believe you can validate all input urls for correctness :)

Answer (score 0):

for php,

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?m)^(?!https?:\/\/.+)(\S+)/',"http://$1",$str);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, is there a code that would work with php? I completely forgot to say that I was working with php in my original post.

Comment: @Charlie the php tag was edited in after the fact.  The original question didn't mention a language.

Comment: @Charlie not sure if it's your downvote or not, but yes ideally it'd be deleted but a comment generally suffices, a downvote is uncalled for since the answerer doesn't deserve to lose rep just because the questioner was unclear.

Comment: @Davy8, thanks for your rightful support. As you said, original question did mention about the target language. And also, since I do not know php, It takes long time to find php solution.

Comment: @Gursel, @Davy8, It's really simple: If you delete the answer the reputation will go back to what it was before my downvote automatically. My downvote is pretty necessary instead since this answer is no more accepted for such a question. It's not for the good of you or the OP, it's for the good of SO and users that will browser this questions after us looking for the same trouble, finding answers that just don't fit the question.

Comment: @Chariliepiga, well, your arguments were plausible but after I have added answer for php, they are not valid arguments anymore.

Comment: You should just delete the Java part imho.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to fix your URL :)

```
function addHttp( $url )
{
    if ( !preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url) )
    {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Search for 'http' and 'https' in the submitted URL, if search returned null add 'http' to the beginning. 
With Javascript:
var mystring="example.com";
var normal=-1;
var secured=-1;
normal=mystring.search(/http/i);
secured=mystring.search(/https/i);
and so on

Comment: Not javascript related question